# Skyrim Dragonborn: Traveling from and to Solstheim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dragonborn

I am at Solstheim for the Dragonborn DLC and I want to go back to Skyrim. The problem is that I don't have enough money to go back and forth. I have many items on Solstheim that I would like to take back to Whiterun.

What is the best way to travel with all the items?

I am trying to travel to Skyrim with all the items, but it doesn't let me do that. Any way to avoid this?

Comment: You don't need to use money to fast travel between Skyrim and Solstheim after you've made the first trip. What is the game telling you when it "doesn't let you?" Are you perhaps _overburdened_?

Comment: I am overburndned

Comment: You're overburdened with valuable loot AND you don't have enough money to travel?  What are you hording?  Brooms?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I am at Solstheim for the Dragonborn DLC and I want to go back to
>   Skyrim. The problem is that I don't have enough money to go back and
>   forth.

Once you reach Solstheim for the first time, you'll get fast travel points unlocked on both the Solstheim and Skyrim world maps. They're roughly in the lower left and upper right corners, respectively. Using these lets you fast travel as normal between the two continents; it costs no money, so your lack of funds should not be an issue.

> I have many items on Solstheim that I would like to take back to
>   Whiterun.
>
> What is the best way to travel with all the items?
>
> I am trying to travel to Skyrim with all the items, but it doesn't let
>   me do that. Any way to avoid this?

Fast travel as above is subject to the usual restrictions about being overburdened (i.e., you can't do it when you're carrying too much). If you're having trouble with the game "not letting you" bring all your items back to Skyrim at once because you're overburdened, either store some in a safe container and bring them over in batches, or drink a few potions that increase your carry weight beforehand, or get on a horse. Additional notes on [various other ways to circumvent carry weight limits can be found at UESPWiki](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Encumbrance).

Comment: or use one of the vendors in Raven Rock to sell your stuff

Answer (score 0):

Just use fast travel! Open the map and select Skyrim. You can choose any available location of Skyrim as your travel point, but you'll load up near Windhelm. Than again open your map and fast travel anywhere you want. Same thing about going back to Solstheim.